# Graphing using 2D array

Tags: java, debugging, multidimensional-array, formatting, char

I have been going around this problem for a while now and i can't seem to debug my program. 
I have created a graph using 2d arrays and i am trying to put an 'X' over the x and y coordinate points. Then i am trying to plot a least square regression line on top of the points. 
Here is my code snippet:

```
char[][] graph = new char[21][42];

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
 graph[21 - 1 - yCoords[i]][xCoords[i] + 1] = 'X';
}

// plot the regression line
for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
 int yPred = Math.round(yMean + slope * (i - xMean)); // calculate regression value
 graph[21-1-yPred][i + 1] = graph[21-1-yPred][i + 1 ] == 'X' ? '*' : '-'; //problem somewhere here
}

//This is how i initialized my array
 public static void initializeArray(char[][] charArray) {
  for(int k =0; k< charArray.length; k++) {
      for(int d = 0; d < charArray[0].length;d++) {
        charArray[k][d] = ' ';
      }
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; ++i) {
    charArray[i][0] = '/';
  }
  charArray[20][0] = '+';

  for (int i = 1; i < charArray[0].length; ++i) {
    charArray[20][i] = '-';
  }
}
```

> Please remember that this is not the complete code.If anyone has a hard time figuring out the problem then comment below and i will explain or provide more code to my problem.

**Right now i am getting this output.**

[image]

**My expected output is this:**

[image]

The problem seems to be with plotting the regression line. So i am using "X"s to represent the points, "-"s the regression line segments, and "*"s where a line segment and a point are located at the same spot. 
I am willing to provide more details. Can anyone help me with bug please.

Comment: It appears you are plotting from 0 to 'graph.length'.   graph.length is equal to the length of the first dimension, so 21.  If you count the dashes in your chart, you will see there are 21 of them.

Comment: So how can i get around that problem? @Jamie

Comment: Well, you could try graph[0].length

Comment: I did try that but it gives me array out of bounds exception? @Jamie

Comment: Not knowing where you are getting an index out of bounds exception, I am going to guess it is because you are then attempting to plot a mark past the length of the x dimension (42) on this instruction:  graph[21-1-yPred][i + 1].   The i+1 is pushing past the end of the array in the x dimension.

Comment: Yea it is giving me error at that line. I can post more code if you want. I don't know how to get the correct output now. @Jamie

Comment: By the way x-coordinates are in the range [0, 40] and y-coordinates in the range [1, 20], if that helps. @Jamie

Comment: The error is not due to the `i+1` pushing past the range, it has got to do with the `graph[21-1-yPred]`. Here is the stack trace: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at main (java:69)` @Jamie

Comment: The line 69 is when i am trying to plot the '-' or '*' chars. I removed +1 from the `i+1` and it showed me above error so that is not the problem, i think. Is it possible for you to help me? @Jamie

Comment: I just realized that it is the line `for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++)` that is causing all this problem.

Comment: Thank you Jamie i was able to debug my program :) @Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem, here is what i did to get the correct output.
All i had to do was put -1 while looping to avoid index out of bounds exception.
ere is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < graph[0].length - 1; i++) {
 int yPred = (int) (yMean + (slope * (i - xMean)));
 if(yPred > 0 && yPred < 21) {
   graph[21 - 1- yPred][i+1] = graph[21 - 1- yPred][i+1] == 'X' ? '*' : '-';
  }
```